# Android - Phonegap - A network error has occurred

Tags: android, cordova

**My environment:**
Eclipse SDK 4.2.1
Cordova 2.2.0 (Phonegap)
Target platform: Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15)

I have tried searching through many forums (including this one) and can't seem to find the solution to this problem.

First, links between pages in the *`assets/www`* directory work fine. However, on one of the pages, I have:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I have also tried  `rel="external"` as an attribute of the  but the result is the same.

I have specfied google.com in the Android whitelist according to the directions by adding:

```
<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
```

to the res/xml/config.xml file.

The result from clicking on the above link is:

> Application Error
>   A network error occurred. (http://www.google.com/)

and the app crashes.

I get the result on both the AVD Manager (emulator) set for API Level 15 as well as a functional device (HTC One X with Android 4.0.3). Both of which can otherwise get to the Internet.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

> D/Cordova (  560):
>   onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) D/chromium( 
>   560): Unknown chromium error: -400 D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onPageStarted,http://www.google.com/) D/Cordova (  560):
>   CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Descripti on=A
>   network error occurred. URL=http://www.google.com/ D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-1,"url":"http://www
>   .google.com/","description":"A network error occurred."}) D/DroidGap(
>   560): onMessage(onPageStarted,http://www.google.com/) D/Cordova ( 
>   560): onPageFinished(http://www.google.com/) D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onNativeReady,null) D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onPageFinished,http://www.google.com/) D/SoftKeyboardDetect(
>   560): Ignore this event D/Cordova (  560):
>   onPageFinished(http://www.google.com/) D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onNativeReady,null) D/DroidGap(  560):
>   onMessage(onPageFinished,http://www.google.com/)

The only time I've ever seen a -400 error is when the internet
permission is missing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a fixed whitelist?

I usually go fine with:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The problem could be that Google is forwarding to another port (https/443), so the subdomain specification won't help.

Or you could try it without specifying the protocol:

```
<access origin="google.com" subdomains="true" />
```

Or try using the wildcards [as described here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml):

```
<access origin="*google.com*" />
```